# Can't create a C ++ project on eclipse C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, eclipse-cdt

`Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Mars Release (4.5.0)
Build id: 20150621-1200` for my first C++ program. But even though i typed in the correct codes its showing a bug and can't run it, when click run it displays "Launch failed. Binary not found". Am using Macbook and OSX Yosemite. The following is my codes and project directory. Please help me on this issue. Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
const double CAPACITY = 3.78;
const double COST = 0.38;
const double PROFIT = 0.27;

int main()
{
    int total_milk;
    double no_of_cartons;
    double profit_value;
    double total_cost;
    cout<<"enter total amount of milk"<< endl;
    cin>>total_milk;
    no_of_cartons =  total_milk/CAPACITY;
    total_cost = total_milk * COST;
    profit_value = total_milk * PROFIT;

    cout<<"no. of cartons = "<<no_of_cartons<< endl;
    cout<<"total cost =  "<< total_cost<< endl;
    cout<<"Profit value = "<< profit_value << endl;

    cin.ignore();
    cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

and my project directory:

[image]

Comment: Two things: First, switch from Problems to the Console tab and see if the build command and output give you a better hint of what went wrong and where than the truncated Problems view. At the very least you can paste the output text into your question in place of the picture. Second, Googling "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64" is quite rich in answers, usually mis-configured libraries. Can't really test your config from over here, so I recommend doing a websearch and seeing if anyone matches your library requirements.

Comment: I've clicked build all from project option. Now am facing a new error named `couldn't determine version of valgrind`? Why is that so?

Comment: Very possible that you don't have valgrind installed, don't know if it comes stock with Mac's devtools, but did install a package with a valgrind dependency.

Comment: I've installed valgrid, but still showing this error.